# Purity of mixed states as a function of radial distance from origin of Bloch ball

Tags: quantum-state, mathematics, density-matrix, bloch-sphere, state-space-geometry

[@AHusain](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/434/ahusain?tab=profile) mentions [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5600/homeomorphism-corresponding-to-the-set-of-mixed-states-within-the-bloch-sphere/5601#5601) that the purity of a qubit state can be expressed as a function of the radius from the center of a Bloch sphere. The state corresponding to the origin is maximally mixed whereas the states corresponding to the boundary points are pure. So far, I haven't seen this fact written anywhere explicitly. What would be the mathematical proof for this claim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A density matrix $\rho$ has the properties of being Hermitian, non-negative and has trace 1.

Any $2\times 2$ matrix can be written in the form
$$
\rho=\frac{n_0\mathbb{I}+\vec{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}{2}.
$$
The trace being 1 fixes that $n_0=1$, while the Hermitian property imposes that $\vec{n}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, where $\vec{\sigma}$ is the vector of the 3 Pauli matrices. The eigenvalues are
$$
\frac12(1\pm\sqrt{\vec{n}\cdot\vec{n}}),
$$
so it's non-negative iff $|\vec{n}|\leq 1$. In the case where the length is 1, the eigenvalues are 0,1 so $\rho$ is a projector onto a pure state.

Now let's consider the purity, $\text{Tr}(\rho^2)$. In this way of writing, we have
$$
\text{Tr}(\rho^2)=\frac12(1+\vec{n}\cdot\vec{n})
$$
Clearly, the largest value of the purity is 1, for pure states, and the smallest value corresponds to $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{n}=0$, i.e. the maximally mixed state.

Now, how do we depict a state on the Bloch Sphere? We simply plot $\vec{n}$, so the distance from the centre of the sphere is given by $|\vec{n}|=\sqrt{2\text{Tr}(\rho^2)-1}$.

---

## Proof of the basic properties

Let's say we have a density matrix of the form
$$
\rho=\sum_ip_i|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|,
$$
where $\sum_ip_i=1$. Trivially, $\rho$ has trace 1 and is Hermitian. Non-negative matrices satisfy the property
$$
\langle\phi|\rho|\phi\rangle\geq 0\qquad\forall|\phi\rangle.
$$
So, consider a state $|\phi\rangle$:
$$
\langle\phi|\rho|\phi\rangle=\sum_ip_i|\langle\phi|\psi_i\rangle|^2.
$$
Every term on the right-hand side must be non-negative, and hence $\rho$ is non-negative.

Comment: How does trace being 1 fix n_0 to be 1?

Comment: @EeshStarryn Pauli matrices have trace  0. Identity has trace 2.

Answer (score 5):

Let me supplement the other answer by also showing what happens in the general case of the Bloch representation of generic qudits of dimension $d$.

Let $\rho$ be an arbitrary state over $d$ modes, that is, a $d\times d$ positive semi-definite Hermitian matrix with unit trace.

As any other Hermitian matrix, we can decompose it in terms of a basis of Hermitian matrices, writing it as something like $\rho=\sum_k c_k\sigma_k$ with $\sigma_k$ an orthonormal basis of Hermitians and $c_k\in\mathbb R$.
There are many ways to choose such a basis for the Hermitian matrices, but a fairly natural choice is to include the *identity matrix* in it. If we do, the constraint of orthogonality automatically imposes that all the other elements of the basis must be traceless (because we must have $\text{Tr}(\mathbb I^\dagger\sigma_k)=\operatorname{Tr}(\sigma_k)=0$). Moreover, we remember that we must have $\text{Tr}(\rho)=1$, and thus we can write the decomposition of $\rho$ as:
$$\rho=\frac{1}{d}\left(\mathbb I+\sum_k c_k\sigma_k\right),$$
where $\text{Tr}(\sigma_j\sigma_k)=\delta_{jk}d$.
Note that this choice of normalisation is conventional (we could have equally written $\rho=\mathbb I/d+\sum_k c_k\sigma_k$ with the $\sigma_k$ normalised to one), but is somewhat "natural" in that it puts $\sigma_k$ to a more even footing with $\mathbb I$, whose normalisation is instead "forced" by the normalisation constraint on $\rho$ (of course, this is conventional as well, but is a "very established" convention).

It is now not hard to compute $\text{Tr}(\rho^2)$, and find it equal to
$$\text{Tr}(\rho^2)=\frac{1}{d}\left(1+\sum_k c_k^2\right)=\frac{1}{d}(1+\lvert\vec c\rvert^2).$$

The state $\rho$ being pure means that it is a projector over some pure state, $\rho=\lvert\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi\rvert$, and thus satisfies $\text{Tr}(\rho^2)=1$.
It then follows that $\rho$ is pure if and only if $|\vec c|=\sqrt{d-1}$.

It should be noted that while this result could seem to suggest that the state space for higher-dimensional systems is not significantly more complex than the Bloch sphere we have for qubits, this is far from the case. Indeed, the state space is in general not a (hyper)sphere, nor an (hyper)ellipse or other simple geometrical figure. [It stretches by different amounts at different angles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/425101/58382), and [its boundary contains non-pure states](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6025/55).
Nevertheless, at least the length of pure states is easy to compute.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of proving that the purity (or any other property which only depends on the eigenvalues of $\rho$) can only depend on the distance from the center of the Bloch sphere is rotational invariance: Rotating a density matrix $\rho\mapsto U\rho U^\dagger$ corresponds to a rotation on the Bloch sphere.  Thus, any property which only depends on the eigenvalues (which do not change under $\rho\mapsto U\rho U^\dagger$) can only depend on the distance from the center.

To get an explicit formula, you can then e.g. restrict to diagonal density matrices.